# What is the main technical focus of Bushin Ryu?

Tags: karate

I have met many practitioners of Bushin Ryu over the years and all seemed very skillful. It seems an admirable martial art and something I aspire to. However, I am unsure what exactly the focus is of this style. And specifically -

**What is the main technical focus of Bushin Ryu?**

Comment: Really? Bushin Ryu has been around for a lot longer than Street Fighter.. There are several manifestations of the art around the world - all originating  in Malaysia.In Canada it is Okinawan Karate/Jujitsu combined , as it is in the USA..In NZ , Australia and the UK it is Okinawan karate-jutsu/aikijutsu combined.No energy balls and lots of real life impact.

Comment: There are many martial arts with bushin ryu in the name can you be more specific ? Bushin just translates to martial thought or something to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

As was hinted to in the comments, it seems that "Bushin Ryu" is a freestyle martial art that is a combination of various other arts, with components of Jiu-jitsu, Ninjutsu, Aiki Jujutsu, Aikido, Hapkido, Karate and Kobujutsu (Japanese Classical Weapons Training).
**source**: [Bushin Ryu Aiki Bujutsu - 'School of the Samurai'](http://mesamartialarts.com/bushin-ryu-aiki-bujutsu/).

From what I understand, there is no real technical focus, and it blends various martial arts into something new. I think the following quote makes clear that there is no clear focus present in this style:

> [Bushin Ryu is a] self-protection [discipline] that includes an extensive variety of strikes, kicks, joint locks, throws, pressure points, ground survival and disarming techniques. The result is a practical, comprehensive self defense system that is enjoyable to learn and truly effective in realistic situations.

**source**: [Bushin Ryu Aiki Bujutsu](http://www.budoshingikankyokai.org/bushin-ryu-aiki-bujutsu.html)

It does, however, seem to strive to conserve the classical way of Japanese Samurai training:

> [The] school of authentic Japanese Bujutsu [is a] self-defense-based
>   Japanese martial arts emerging in the modern era but taught in the
>   tradition of the feudal era [...]

**source**: [Bushin Ryu Aiki Bujutsu World Federation](http://bushinryuaikibujutsu.com/)

This latter contrasts with another freestyle self-defense system composed of various other disciplines, namely the Israeli [Krav Maga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krav_Maga). Krav Maga is focused on real-life practical solutions for self-defense techniques designed for the Israel Defense Forces (and other military forces). Krav Maga is therefore focused on efficiency, while Bushin Ryu has a strong focus on the classic Japanese budo.

Comment: You are largely correct with respect to the North American derivatives of this art. The Pacific and European variants are far more closely aligned with the traditional Okinawan and Japanese arts - (in a very small nutshell) their technical focus is on knowledge and mastery of bunkai and tuite. Disclaimer: I know the author of this question very well and the question is a little deeper than it appears - I will post an answer here sometime in the future, a good answer would be at least a book chapter in length :)

Comment: BTW, comparing the Pacific variants of this art with Krava Maga is like comparing a rusty middle ages broadsword (Krav) with a katana made by a master craftsman (Bushin Ryu) - they are worlds apart :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not an actual traditional martial art.

This style is an amalgamation of the japanese styles that the founder seems to have some experience in, Namely Akido, but the actual founding location and headquarters of this "martial art" is in Phoenix, Arizona.
A quick google search attempting to find any background info on this Bushin Ryu shows me that Capcom video game classic, Street Fighter,  is the oldest and only record of Bushin Ryu, the name Ryu sound familar? 
Every style of martial art has an easy and transparent lineage through its history of masters.
The founder of this particular martial art is only 35 and already an 8th Dan?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your answer would be greatly improved if you provided some references/links to your claims. Could you edit it to add those? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site Steve. Note that you've traced one of the derivatives, there are others that are based on traditional Okinawan practices. It's quite common for someone to evolve or transform an art when they set up to teach it, hence why there are derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

I have done Bushin Ryu in New Zealand for 30years. WE here are a school of Karate but would be closer, in modern language, to 2nd era Ju Jitsu (goshin jutsu), but Aikijutsu is also part of our syllabus...we were a MMA school before MMA was a thing and in NZ we had the early MMA people come in and train.

Our system is based in Ryu Kyu Kenpo kata practice (as is shotokan karate) and the application of those techniques - Bunkai. The Aikijutsu and Ju Jitsu inform our close quarter combat and ne waza. Hard sparing and nasty fitness ruled the Nelson Bushin Ryu school under our instructor Mike.

Cheers Simon Tarrant 4th dan Bushin Ryu